# Cannot replicate documentation example on scheduling a task with Schtasks.exe using an XML file

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, xml, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

### Summary

I am following the examples of the [official Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/boot-trigger-example--xml-) regarding using the task scheduler to create a task that is defined in XML. My objective is to implement the example of launching Notepad whenever the system boots.

### Details

Following the steps of the documentation, I have created an XML file with the contents of the link above and placed it in `C:\start-notepad.xml`. To register the task, I opened PowerShell as an administrator and run

```
PS C:\> schtasks /create /XML start-notepad.xml /tn start-notepad
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "start-notepad" has successfully been created.

PS C:\> schtasks /Query /tn start-notepad

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
start-notepad                            N/A                    Ready
```

Now, when I restart the machine (VM on VirtualBox) I would expect the Notepad application to start, but it doesn't. Either the documentation is lacking something, or I am doing wrong...

### start-notepad.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe when
the system is booted.
-->
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</Date>
        <Author>AuthorName</Author>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Description>Starts Notepad on system boot.</Description>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <BootTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</StartBoundary>
            <EndBoundary>2026-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</EndBoundary>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT5M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
        </BootTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal>
            <UserId>Administrator</UserId>
            <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    </Settings>
    <Actions>
        <Exec>
            <Command>notepad.exe</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

### Task Scheduler

The task has correctly been added in the Task Scheduler, but nothing happens when I click "Run", neither when I reboot...

[image: Task scheduler]

Comment: Create a task in Task Scheduler and export as xml. Compare the difference.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go, thx

Comment: Check the task manager for a notepad.exe process. It might've been started in the background. Task manager has feature to launch processes in a desktop session which is the only time that you actually see the program in the foreground.

Comment: @megamorf I checked the Task Manager, couldn't find notepad there.

Comment: I am following @Mark's approach now, will first try to make the task work by creating it within the Task Schedule and when I verify that it works on startup, I'll export it and compare the diff with the example from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing **2 things**:

### 1. Use `LogonTrigger` next to the `BootTrigger`

Solution was suggested here: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html

I replaced:

```xml
<Triggers>
  <BootTrigger>
    <StartBoundary>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</StartBoundary>
    <EndBoundary>2026-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</EndBoundary>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT5M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
  </BootTrigger>
</Triggers>
```

with:

```xml
<Triggers>
  <BootTrigger>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  </BootTrigger>
  <LogonTrigger>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  </LogonTrigger>
</Triggers>
```

### 2. Use the correct `Principal`

I found that unless I used the currently logged in user, Notepad would never launch on boot (or logon). In [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1005923/585125) I found the suggestion to use the `builtin\users` to make Notepad launch no matter which user logs in.

I replaced:

```xml
<Principal>
  <UserId>Administrator</UserId>
  <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
</Principal>
```

with:

```xml
<Principal>
  <GroupId>S-1-5-32-545</GroupId>
  <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
</Principal>
```

You can find more information regarding what this `GrouId` is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

### Final working XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2020-07-29T00:00:00-00:00</Date>
        <Author>AuthorName</Author>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Description>Starts Notepad on system boot.</Description>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <BootTrigger>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </BootTrigger>
        <LogonTrigger>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </LogonTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
      <Principal>
          <GroupId>S-1-5-32-545</GroupId>
          <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
      </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    </Settings>
    <Actions>
        <Exec>
            <Command>notepad.exe</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```